# "CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing " : while calling deployed AWS Api gateway

Tags: javascript, rest, api, amazon-web-services

I am trying to consume a restful api deployed on aws cloud which returns me a Json, i want the json to be displayed on the browser using javascript. But i am failing to achieve to do so.
Below is my index.html and hello.js file :

//index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hello jQuery</title>

        <script src="hello.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p class="greeting-id">The ID is </p>
            <p class="greeting-content">The content is </p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

//hello.js

```
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("get", "https://xxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev",  true);
    xhr.onload = function(){  
    //do something
   };
xhr.send(null);
```

Any help will be appreciated, i am new to this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you testing on Chrome? Chrome, or any modern browser doesn't allow cors by default for security purposes. You can search for disabling it, or install an extension, extensions can make cors request. Just search for it. And if you are serving these files from a local server like express, you will have to enable cors there.

Comment: thanks you @AbhilashSingh. I am testing it on firefox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to allow access control in the .config file of your server.

Secondly, you can get the data using http or jQuery ajax get and assign it to something like jsonStr

Finally, in your function, do 
var jsonStr = JSON.stringify(jsonVar);
document.getElementsByClassName('greeting-content').innerHTML = jsonStr;